# Uploading of files using sap.m.UploadCollection in Openui5 with a backend servlet doesn't work

Tags: sapui5

I have written a backend servlet to handle the upload of files using the `instantUpload` feature of `sap.m.UploadCollection` in Openui5. As I am uploading multiple files to the server, I have chosen the `sap.m.UploadCollection` instead of the `sap.ui.unified.FileUploader`. When I try to parse out a list of FileItem instances from the HttpServletRequest in the servlet, it gives me the exception

> the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream

The `ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)` is obviously returning me a `false` and confirms me that it isn't a multipart/form-data request.

**XML Code:**

```
<UploadCollection id="UploadCollection1"
            multiple="true"
            sameFilenameAllowed="true"
            showSeparators="All"
            change="onChangeUploadCollection"
            fileDeleted="onFileDeleted"
            selectionChange="onSelectionChange"
            uploadComplete="onUploadCompleteUploadCollection"
            beforeUploadStarts="onBeforeUploadStarts"
            items="{path : '/record/uploadcollectionitems', templateShareable : 'true'}"
            uploadUrl="{/record/upload}"
            mode="SingleSelectLeft">

            <toolbar>
                <OverflowToolbar id="myId1">
                    <Title id="attachmentTitle1" />
                    <ToolbarSpacer />
                    <Button id="downloadButton1" text="Download" press="onDownloadItem"
                        enabled="false" type="Transparent"></Button>
                </OverflowToolbar>
            </toolbar>
            <items>
                <UploadCollectionItem documentId="{documentId}"
                    fileName="{fileName}" mimeType="{mimeType}" 
                    url="{url}" enableEdit="true" enableDelete="true"
                    visibleDelete="true" visibleEdit="true"
                    statuses="{path : '/record/uploadcollectionitems', templateShareable : 'true'}"
                    selected="false">
                    <statuses>
                        <ObjectStatus title="{Status}" visible="false"
                            state="{state}" icon="{icon}" iconDensityAware="{iconDensityAware}"
                        textDirection="{textDirection}" />
                    </statuses>
                </UploadCollectionItem>
            </items>
</UploadCollection>
```

The `uploadURL` in the XML points to the Servlet, which starts executing after the selection of the file is done on the front-end.

If I choose to use the **FileUploader** instead of the **UploadCollection**, it successfully encodes the request as a multipart/form-data, but it does not fulfill my requirements.

I have also tried adding `content-type`as a HeaderParameter and setting it to `multipart/form-data`, in order to make the **request** as a  `multipart/form-data`. Since such a step is not advisable, I have aborted it mid-way.

Since the sap.m.UploadCollection control uses the sap.ui.unified.FileUploader control and contains dependencies to this control, it is confusing as to why the former would not send the HttpServletRequest as a `multipart/form-data`.

**Note:** 
I have not included the corresponding **JavaScript** code or the **Servlet**
code for brevity purposes. I'll be happy to include them if required.

Answer (score 1):

If you take closer look into the code you'll see that the FileUploader used by the UploadCollection is always instantiated with useMultipart set to false. You do not have chance to change that unless you intervene the creation of the FileUploader. I'm not sure why this approach has been taken.

Comment: Thank You for your response.. Instead of intervening in the creation of the FileUploader instance and setting the useMultipart to true, I have actually used the 'copy' and 'copyLarge' functions of the commons.io.IOUtils, to upload the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UploadCollection with multipart.
In the controller, you need to have:

> ```
> onBeforeUploadStarts: function(oEvent) {
> var oUploadCollection = this.getView().byId("UploadCollection");
>          oUploadCollection = oUploadCollection._getFileUploader();
>          oUploadCollection.setUseMultipart(true);
> }
> ```